# PHP rewrite Metabox does not work

Tags: php

I have a Metabox in my wordpress, and I need the code in this script to insert but I can not get it to work.

The code I need to enter the:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'barcode', true );
```

in this code under the title Code

```
$output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';

$output .= '</div><div style="clear:both"></div>';
$output .= '<div class="description">';
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? I mean, you are telling us what you need, and then you include the code you need, why not just paste in the code as you've explained yourself?

Comment: how can I rewrite the above code that there funksioniert at lower